# iOS App launches then instantly closes in simulator/xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

any app I work on in Mavericks 10.9.1 / Xcode 5.0 / iOS Simulator 7.0.1 / SpriteKit seems to launch fine, but closes back to home as soon as it finishes loading the app.

This even happens on new projects I start in Xcode, using the basic "Hello, World!" template.

Using the basic SpriteKit template on a NEW project, I receive the following errors upon launch in iOS Simulator with no modifications to the code:

**UPDATE #1:** I'd also like to note, that after being forced to the Home Screen, all the other standard apps on iOS Simulator (Safari, Maps, etc.) function normally, implying that it may simply be the code itself. However, considering this happens on a brand new project straight out of the default Xcode 5.0.2 installation, I'm at a loss as to the cause.

**System Log:**

```
Marker - Feb 14, 2014, 2:07:00 PM
Feb 14 14:07:02 My-Mac-Pro.local SpringBoard[530] <Warning>: LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image

Feb 14 14:07:02 My-Mac-Pro com.apple.iphonesimulator.launchd.581ea05d[518] (UIKitApplication:MY.TestTestTest[0x871c][577]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1

Feb 14 14:07:02 My-Mac-Pro.local backboardd[520] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:MY.TestTestTest[0x871c]' exited abnormally with exit status 1
```

**Console Log:**

```
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: 0xa4092b0: v16i8 = X86ISD::PSHUFB 0xa407bb8, 0xa408118 [ID=695]

  0xa407bb8: v16i8 = llvm.x86.sse2.packuswb.128 0xa407b30, 0xa407a20, 0xa407aa8 [ORD=1594] [ID=694]

0xa407b30: i32 = TargetConstant<2543> [ORD=1594] [ID=37]
0xa407a20: v8i16 = llvm.x86.sse2.packssdw.128 0xa407998, 0xa407448, 0xa4075e0 [ORD=1592] [ID=693]
  0xa407998: i32 = TargetConstant<2541> [ORD=1592] [ID=36]
  0xa407448: v4i32 = llvm.x86.sse2.cvttps2dq 0xabe63e0, 0xa4073c0 [ORD=1582] [ID=691]
    0xabe63e0: i32 = TargetConstant<2528> [ORD=1151] [ID=25]
    0xa4073c0: v4f32 = fadd 0xa407338, 0xb3e70e8 [ORD=1581] [ID=688]
      0xa407338: v4f32 = fmul 0xa406cc8, 0xa407e60 [ORD=1580] [ID=685]
        0xa406cc8: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3f4d78, 0xa406c40, 0xabf75e0 [ORD=1567] [ID=682]
          0xa3f4d78: i32 = TargetConstant<2700> [ORD=1480] [ID=35]
          0xa406c40: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.max.ps 0xa3f4b58, 0xa406bb8, 0xa407ee8 [ORD=1566] [ID=679]
            0xa3f4b58: i32 = TargetConstant<2698> [ORD=1479] [ID=34]
            0xa406bb8: v4f32,ch = load 0xa406b30, 0xabe62d0, 0xb3e4208<LD16[%604](tbaa=!"omnipotent char")> [ORD=1565] [ID=675]
              0xabe62d0: i32 = FrameIndex<1> [ORD=978] [ID=4]
              0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
            0xa407ee8: v4f32 = bitcast 0xa4072b0 [ID=120]
              0xa4072b0: v4i32 = BUILD_VECTOR 0xa407228, 0xa407228, 0xa407228, 0xa407228 [ID=100]




          0xabf75e0: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa3f6118, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=132]
            0xa3f6118: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xabf7f70 [ID=121]
              0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
              0xabf7f70: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabe58a8 [ID=101]

            0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
        0xa407e60: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa408090, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=135]
          0xa408090: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xa407f70 [ID=124]
            0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
            0xa407f70: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3f4be0 [ID=104]
              0xa3f4be0: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=67]
          0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
      0xb3e70e8: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa3f6338, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=133]
        0xa3f6338: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xb3e43a0 [ID=122]
          0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
          0xb3e43a0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabe61c0 [ID=102]
            0xabe61c0: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=65]
        0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
  0xa4075e0: v4i32 = llvm.x86.sse2.cvttps2dq 0xabe63e0, 0xa407558 [ORD=1585] [ID=690]
    0xabe63e0: i32 = TargetConstant<2528> [ORD=1151] [ID=25]
    0xa407558: v4f32 = fadd 0xa4074d0, 0xb3e70e8 [ORD=1584] [ID=687]
      0xa4074d0: v4f32 = fmul 0xa406e60, 0xa407e60 [ORD=1583] [ID=684]
        0xa406e60: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3f4d78, 0xa406dd8, 0xabf75e0 [ORD=1571] [ID=681]
          0xa3f4d78: i32 = TargetConstant<2700> [ORD=1480] [ID=35]
          0xa406dd8: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.max.ps 0xa3f4b58, 0xa406d50, 0xa407ee8 [ORD=1570] [ID=677]
            0xa3f4b58: i32 = TargetConstant<2698> [ORD=1479] [ID=34]
            0xa406d50: v4f32,ch = load 0xa406b30, 0xa405d50, 0xb3e4208<LD16[%608](tbaa=!"omnipotent char")> [ORD=1569] [ID=674]
              0xa405d50: i32 = add 0xabe62d0, 0xb3dc798 [ORD=1465] [ID=73]


              0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
            0xa407ee8: v4f32 = bitcast 0xa4072b0 [ID=120]
              0xa4072b0: v4i32 = BUILD_VECTOR 0xa407228, 0xa407228, 0xa407228, 0xa407228 [ID=100]




          0xabf75e0: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa3f6118, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=132]
            0xa3f6118: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xabf7f70 [ID=121]
              0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
              0xabf7f70: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabe58a8 [ID=101]

            0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
        0xa407e60: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa408090, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=135]
          0xa408090: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xa407f70 [ID=124]
            0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
            0xa407f70: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3f4be0 [ID=104]
              0xa3f4be0: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=67]
          0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
      0xb3e70e8: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa3f6338, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=133]
        0xa3f6338: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xb3e43a0 [ID=122]
          0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
          0xb3e43a0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabe61c0 [ID=102]
            0xabe61c0: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=65]
        0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
0xa407aa8: v8i16 = llvm.x86.sse2.packssdw.128 0xa407998, 0xa407778, 0xa407910 [ORD=1593] [ID=692]
  0xa407998: i32 = TargetConstant<2541> [ORD=1592] [ID=36]
  0xa407778: v4i32 = llvm.x86.sse2.cvttps2dq 0xabe63e0, 0xa4076f0 [ORD=1588] [ID=689]
    0xabe63e0: i32 = TargetConstant<2528> [ORD=1151] [ID=25]
    0xa4076f0: v4f32 = fadd 0xa407668, 0xb3e70e8 [ORD=1587] [ID=686]
      0xa407668: v4f32 = fmul 0xa407008, 0xa407e60 [ORD=1586] [ID=683]
        0xa407008: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3f4d78, 0xa406f70, 0xabf75e0 [ORD=1575] [ID=680]
          0xa3f4d78: i32 = TargetConstant<2700> [ORD=1480] [ID=35]
          0xa406f70: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.max.ps 0xa3f4b58, 0xa406ee8, 0xa407ee8 [ORD=1574] [ID=676]
            0xa3f4b58: i32 = TargetConstant<2698> [ORD=1479] [ID=34]
            0xa406ee8: v4f32,ch = load 0xa406b30, 0xa405e60, 0xb3e4208<LD16[%612](tbaa=!"omnipotent char")> [ORD=1573] [ID=673]
              0xa405e60: i32 = add 0xabe62d0, 0xabe3fa0 [ORD=1467] [ID=75]


              0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
            0xa407ee8: v4f32 = bitcast 0xa4072b0 [ID=120]
              0xa4072b0: v4i32 = BUILD_VECTOR 0xa407228, 0xa407228, 0xa407228, 0xa407228 [ID=100]




          0xabf75e0: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa3f6118, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=132]
            0xa3f6118: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xabf7f70 [ID=121]
              0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
              0xabf7f70: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabe58a8 [ID=101]

            0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
        0xa407e60: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa408090, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=135]
          0xa408090: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xa407f70 [ID=124]
            0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
            0xa407f70: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3f4be0 [ID=104]
              0xa3f4be0: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=67]
          0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
      0xb3e70e8: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa3f6338, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=133]
        0xa3f6338: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xb3e43a0 [ID=122]
          0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
          0xb3e43a0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabe61c0 [ID=102]
            0xabe61c0: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=65]
        0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
  0xa407910: v4i32 = llvm.x86.sse2.cvttps2dq 0xabe63e0, 0xa407888 [ORD=1591] [ID=672]
    0xabe63e0: i32 = TargetConstant<2528> [ORD=1151] [ID=25]
    0xa407888: v4f32 = fadd 0xa407800, 0xb3e70e8 [ORD=1590] [ID=670]
      0xa407800: v4f32 = fmul 0xa4071a0, 0xa407e60 [ORD=1589] [ID=668]
        0xa4071a0: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3f4d78, 0xa407118, 0xabf75e0 [ORD=1579] [ID=666]
          0xa3f4d78: i32 = TargetConstant<2700> [ORD=1480] [ID=35]
          0xa407118: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.max.ps 0xa3f4b58, 0xa406888, 0xa407ee8 [ORD=1578] [ID=664]
            0xa3f4b58: i32 = TargetConstant<2698> [ORD=1479] [ID=34]
            0xa406888: v4f32 = fadd 0xa406800, 0xa3f5460 [ORD=1555] [ID=660]
              0xa406800: v4f32 = fmul 0xa3f6dd8, 0xa406448 [ORD=1554] [ID=656]


              0xa3f5460: v4f32 = llvm.x86.sse.min.ps 0xa3f4d78, 0xa3f53d8, 0xabf75e0 [ORD=1495] [ID=616]



            0xa407ee8: v4f32 = bitcast 0xa4072b0 [ID=120]
              0xa4072b0: v4i32 = BUILD_VECTOR 0xa407228, 0xa407228, 0xa407228, 0xa407228 [ID=100]




          0xabf75e0: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa3f6118, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=132]
            0xa3f6118: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xabf7f70 [ID=121]
              0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
              0xabf7f70: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabe58a8 [ID=101]

            0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
        0xa407e60: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa408090, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=135]
          0xa408090: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xa407f70 [ID=124]
            0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
            0xa407f70: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xa3f4be0 [ID=104]
              0xa3f4be0: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02, float 2.550000e+02>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=67]
          0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]
      0xb3e70e8: v4f32,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa3f6338, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=133]
        0xa3f6338: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xb3e43a0 [ID=122]
          0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
          0xb3e43a0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xabe61c0 [ID=102]
            0xabe61c0: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<4 x float> <float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01, float 5.000000e-01>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=65]
        0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]

  0xa408118: v16i8 = bitcast 0xa407d50 [ID=140]
    0xa407d50: v2i64,ch = load 0x975facc, 0xa408228, 0xb3e4208<LD16[ConstantPool]> [ID=136]
      0xa408228: i32 = add 0xb3e6978, 0xa4081a0 [ID=125]
        0xb3e6978: i32 = X86ISD::GlobalBaseReg [ID=64]
        0xa4081a0: i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0xb405660 [ID=105]
          0xb405660: i32 = TargetConstantPool<<16 x i8> <i8 2, i8 1, i8 0, i8 3, i8 6, i8 5, i8 4, i8 7, i8 10, i8 9, i8 8, i8 11, i8 14, i8 13, i8 12, i8 15>> 0 [TF=2] [ID=68]
      0xb3e4208: i32 = undef [ORD=977] [ID=3]

In function: gldLLVMFPTransform7
```

Comment: Anyone familiar with this? I'm hoping to use this weekend to begin coding proper, as I'm pretty much new to this, and excited to get started.

However, an extensive internet search thus far has not successfully found me an answer or source of the problem.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? I'd like to start working in xcode, but if I can't test the app in iOS Simulator, I can't move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the simulator? ('iOS Simulator menu' > 'Reset Content And Settings...') 
It's not uncommon for the simulator to act funny at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to Xcode 5.1 (The beta version is pretty stable) and as above - reset the content settings of the iOS simulator. It can be fussy at times.

Comment: I can confirm that resetting the content settings of the iOS simulator does not resolve the issue.

I can't upgrade to Xcode 5.1 at this time, as I am not yet subscribed as a developer (which costs $99/yr). I'd be more inclined to do so when I have a product ready to go, but I can't justify it at this time.

That being said, Xcode 5.0.2 should be functional on its own, rather than drop $99 on what I hope will be a working version, with no guarantee it will fix my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In finder select .xcodeproject file. 
Right click and select Show Package content.
Then delete "xcuserdata"
It usually store status of last execution.